# Update a NULL column that was added

Tags: mysql

I'm not a coder, but from time to time I have to interact with out client database. The company I work for does online education. The problem is that we have two SQL databases

Client_personal

client_educational

Client personal keeps all of the name, email, address, phone type of information. Client educational keeps track of what classes they have purchased. I need to take the information from client educational and tag the client personal information in our CRM. The problem is that the the two databases only have one common field "client id" and my CRM only allows me to search for duplicates by client name. So basically I need to add the client name column to my client educational database. I've added it, but it just says null. Anybody have any advise?

Comment: Are they on the same physical machine?

Comment: Before you add that `[Client Name]` column to the `client_educational` database, can I ask a question?  If we now have a `[Client Name]` in BOTH databases, what happens when your client gets married and changes names?  Who is going to update her new name on that `[Client Name]` column you just added to the `client_educational` database?  Do we have a way to make that happen automatically, across both databases?  If not, you may want to go at this another way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but assuming:

- They're on the same machine
- The table is called `clients` in both databases
- The "client name" field is called `clientName` in both databases
- The "client id" field is called `clientID` in both databases
- You want to copy the data from one table into the other as a one off
- You can use a user account with access to both databases

**As always please don't run this on your real data. Try a mock first.**

something like:

```
UPDATE client_educational.clients 
   SET client_educational.clients.clientName = Client_personal.clients.clientName 
   FROM client_educational.clients
   INNER JOIN Client_personal.clients
   ON client_educational.clients.clientID = Client_personal.clients.clientID
```

If you don't actually want to copy data as a one off, you should create a view or use join statements instead.